# How to implement InsertOrUpdate Method for detail entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, dbcontext

I build my repository to use with EntityFramework .One of the problems i faced is  How to handle the InsertOrUpdate method in case like that :

If i have interface method :

```
void InsertOrUpdate(T entity);
```

The implementation of this method works fine with master table like that :

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(Employee employee)
{
    if (employee.EMP_NUM == default(int)) // New entity
    {
        context.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    else        // Existing entity
    {
        context.Employees.Add(employee);
        context.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

---

Now if the employee has many notes like this :

```
EMP_NUM     p.k
From_Date   p.k
Note
```

How to handle the same method for this entity with composite key:

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(EmployeeNote employeeNote)
{
    if (employeeNote.EMP_NUM == default(int)) // New entity
    {

        context.Entry(employeeNote).State = EntityState.Added;
    }
    else        // Existing entity
    {
        context.EmployeeNotes.Add(employeeNote);
        context.Entry(employeeNote).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Comment: I never use composite keys. Every entity inherits from a base class with an integer Id. But if you want to use composite keys there is an article here that might help...http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/05/03/the-key-to-addorupdate/

Comment: @Colin:Could You clarify your solution with an example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a `struct` would be the easiest solution:

```
public struct EmployeeKey
{
    public int k;
    public DateTime d;
}

if (new EmployeeKey{k = employeeNote.EMP_NUM, d = employeeNote.From_Date}
          .Equals(default(EmployeeKey))
{
    context.Entry(employeeNote).State = EntityState.Added;
}
```

`default(struct)` creates a `struct` with the default values of all its members.

On a little sidenote:

This line: `context.Employees.Add(employee);` for an existing entity, shouldn't it be `context.Employees.Attach(employee);`?